# Security updates for .net Framework and Java

Tags: java, .net, security, updates

in my project it is contracted that we deliver the hardware (a computer with Windows 7 installed), our software plus some third party software.

The whole system runs in a restricted area without internet connection. Therefore we are responsible for providing updates for Windows and basically all the third party software installed. As our next release will be a minor one, we should only deliver security updates. Also we had problems in the past with another internal software which didnt run anymore after a .net update. Therefore we should be very careful.

On the delivered system there is currently .net framework 4.7.0 running.
My question is, what is the best way to get security updates for .net framework onto the system? Should we update to 4.7.2? Or is it the best to use the WSUS Offline Updater Generator ?

Same question for java. Currently 8.0.1020.14 is installed. We want to stay with Java 8 but include bugfixes and security updates.

Could you please give me a suggestion what you think are the best options for me?

Thank you